# My Xcode preview does not match what is in the simulator

Tags: ios, xcode

For some reason there is extra space at the top of my UI. I used auto layout to make the button "Monday" snap to the top-middle. I think it has something to do with my segmented control because this doesn't happen in any of my view controllers.

I've tried creating a completely new view controller and still getting the extra space.[Screenshot of Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPex8.png) [Interface Builder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RexTn.png)

Comment: Try showing us the Interface Builder for the view controller.

Comment: Okay I updated it. @Renzo